# log4net: Roll by date, enumerate file by number

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

Previously, my team had been using log4net to roll by maximum file size, and it was generating files like:

```
MyLog.log
MyLog.log.1
MyLog.log.2
etc.
```

Recently, we've switched to

```
<rollingStyle value="Date"/>
<MaxSizeRollBackups value="14"/>
<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd"/>
```

Which now produces filenames like:

```
MyLog.log
MyLog.log20130324
MyLog.log20130323
etc.
```

Is it possible to roll by date and yet still have the log files enumerated like before? If so, how would I do this? I looked all over Log4net's website, but couldn't find a good reference on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this without creating a custom appender. For the RollingFileAppender,
if the rollingStyle is set to Date or Composite (the default), then the next output file name is generated from the base file name + the current time formatted by datePattern.

Comment: That's the conclusion I was coming to as well, but thought I would ask for help.